# how to represent this domain of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have an exercice from a Stewart's book, I don't have the book with me and I don't remember the number and the page...

so the question is to evaluate :
$$\int_{1/ \sqrt 2}^1 \int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^x xy \ dy \ dx + \int_1^\sqrt 2 \int_0^x xy \ dy \ dx + \int_\sqrt 2 ^2 \int_0^\sqrt{4-x^2}  xy \ dy \ dx$$

I can evaluate this, without trouble in polar because I did enough integrations during my life... but I feel like a calculator because there some stuff I don't still understand... I'm still not able to draw the domain of integration...

let's just look the first one :
$$\int_{1/ \sqrt 2}^1 \int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^x xy \ dy \ dx$$
the domain of integration for $x$ isn't a problem. So let's remove it
$$x\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^x y \ dy $$
now how can I draw the domain of integration for $y$ ?
I see it start from $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ looks like a circle. And finished to $y=x$ a line. And between them ?

how can I draw the domain (of the first integral only) ? I would like reasoning in polar and cartesian.

Comment: You are bounded by set $y$ equal to the limits on the inner integral, and $x$ equal to the limits on the outer to find the bounds for your region.  So, $y=x$, $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $x=1$, and $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ are your bounds.  There is only one region within all of those.

Comment: @anorton my problem isn't to evaluate this integral, I know the bounds, but I want to know how to draw the domain

Comment: The way to find the domain is to draw all the bounds, and select the region within.  Once you've done that, you're done.

Comment: @anorton I think I get it this time. put your last comment as answer and you get the point

Comment: @anorton I tested myself on a bunch of examples after several hours of (black metal) break (to not using memory but reasoning). I was able to determine and draw - at ease - all domains I tried. So thx

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments converted to answer:

You are bounded by set y equal to the limits on the inner integral, and x equal to the limits on the outer to find the bounds for your region. So, $y=x$, $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $x=1$, and $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ are your bounds. There is only one region within all of those.

The way to find the domain is to draw all the bounds, and select the region within. Once you've done that, you're done.